# add UIActionSheet without cancel button

Tags: xcode4

i want to use UIActionSheet to allow user to choose one of two modes of my iphone app. so i do not need to show cancel button. i just want to ask him if he want to choose mode one or two.
i tried not to add it but it did not allow me so how can i do it ?

note : i do not want to use alerts.

i use this code for adding UIActionSheet:

```
UIActionSheet *mySheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"choose one" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"tasks" destructiveButtonTitle:@"appointments" otherButtonTitles:nil];


[mySheet showInView:self.view];
```

Comment: This is an activity sheet, not an action sheet. If you meant action sheet, please post the code you have to show the action sheet. An activity sheet you can't customize (except for the activity types).

Comment: yes yes i past the wrong code,, i edit it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"Share" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Mode 1",@"Mode 2", nil];
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
```

Just set the `cancelButtonTitle` to `nil`